# updateSQL command precedes databasechangelog table with current schema name

Tags: liquibase

When I execute the sqloutput command, liquibase 3.2.2 precedes each insert on databasechangelog table with current schema name.

```
INSERT INTO <MY_TEST_SCHEMA>.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, LIQUIBASE) VALUES (...);
```

This forces me to process the outcome files to remove the "MY_TEST_SCHEMA." string, because we execute liquibase against a test schema before we launch the resulting files to production.

I've been using liquibase 2.0.3 for quite long and this behaviour is new in liquibase 3.0.0.

Is there any way to prevent liquibase from adding the schema name? I've already tried to use the defaultSchemaName parameter but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the --outputDefaultSchema=false and --outputDefaultCatalog=false flags to suppress them being included.

It looks like the flag is not followed, at least from the command line in 3.2.2. I created https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2088 and added a fix for 3.3.0 which should be out in the next week or so.

Comment: The flags worked for me with liquibase 3.2.2. This is the command line java -cp ".;c:\<lqbroot>\liquibase-3.2.2\liquibase.jar;<lqbroot>\liquibase-3.2.2\lib\ojdbc14.jar;C:\<lqbroot>\liquibase-3.2.2\lib\snakeyaml-1.13.jar"  liquibase.integration.commandline.Main --outputDefaultSchema=false --outputDefaultCatalog=false --logLevel severe --defaultsFile myprops.properties --contexts dml updateSQL

Thank you

Comment: Actually, the flags work fine on windows but not on Unix, same command line result in prefixed databasechangelog sentences. Does this have any sense? A problem retrieving parameters? maybe uppercase?

Comment: There may be a difference in whether you have them in a liquibase.properties file or directly in the command line arguments. Is there a difference that way for you?

Comment: No, I had already checked. The props files are in the repository and we use the same code/props in the updateSQL executed on workstation (win) and on jenkins (ux). No differences neither on command line args except for the liquibase command (.bat / ux script).